# What is the most effective method for implementing PIA VPN for my home network?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am looking to funnel all of the traffic on my home network through Private Internet Access (or any other VPN provider). At this point, I just use the PIA desktop client which works fine, but only my desktop traffic is going through the VPN. I would like the traffic from all devices (tablets, laptops, TVs) to go through the PIA VPN. I have a Linksys e1200 router that I have flashed dd-wrt onto, so I could set it up at the router. However the e1200 has a weak processor and will likely cause performance issues. I haven’t personally tested this, but I have read about it online (so it must be true). I have also been looking at the Utilite (which has two gigabit ports) and could definitely meet my needs (and could totally replace the e1200) but I think I would be over my head in terms of getting it set up. Anyways, I really would love some suggestions on how to get all of my home network traffic through my PIA VPN.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to do it at the router level.  I'm not familiar with PIA VPN, but from what I understand PIA acts as a secure proxy for internet traffic with anonymization.

You want this to be transparent to your devices (as some might be difficult to configure with PIA).  You've already flashed your current router, so why not test out the internet's theory of performance and [configure it for the PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/#ddwrt_openvpn) using Open VPN.  You literally have nothing to loose.  If you're using PPTP then you should stop, because it's an [insecure protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security).

If you want the easy *route* then I would suggest buying a [ASUS RT-N66U Wireless Router](http://www.flashrouters.com/routers/vpn-types/asus-rtn66u-router-tomatousb-router-privateinternetaccess).  It's a great router, I use it myself.  The link I provide has only one review, but it's exactly your situation.  That's an expensive price though.  [At Newegg you can get it much cheaper](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320091&cm_re=RT-n66u-_-33-320-091-_-Product), which has DD-WRT support built in.  You should be able to [configure it's VPN for PIA with OpenVPN no problem](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/#ddwrt_openvpn).  I really think this is your best bet, with minimal investment.

Here's another guide for [configuring the RT-N66U with OpenVPN](https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202721166-Asus-OpenVPN-Setup-Firmware-3-0-0-4-374-2050-or-newer-).